# Linux C: interactive output

Tags: c, linux, interactive-mode

I'm developing some kind of mysql monitoring tool so I need interactive output like top command.

Is there any lib that can be used for this?

Comment: What do you mean by interactive output?

Answer (score 4):

You may get some good milage out of `ncurses` http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/

Here is a link to the IO-Top source code. It is software that behaves like `top`, but displays information related to IO, rather than CPU.

- http://repo.or.cz/w/iotop.git

Comment: There's also [s-lang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Lang_(programming_library)) as an alternative to ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

`ncurses` was already mentioned. Another `bash` approach is using `dialog`. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog